# How do I find the location of a file?

Tags: wine, files, 20.10, execute-command

I’m new to Ubuntu, and I don’t know how to find the location of a file to follow a tutorial for creating a luncher for Windows programs run through Wine.

[This is the example I’m trying to follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrUAD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In nautilus (the file browser), use the search button and type the name of the file you're looking for, or a part of it. 
Once it's shown, you right click on the icon and look into properties to get the parent directory.
You can even choose the file type, etc.

[image: Search function in Nautilus]